# Cannot enable Diagnostics Log Kernel-Power Thermal-Diagnostic

Tags: windows

When I try to enable Thermal Diagnostic event log I get the code 15003 which means that no ETW provider is registered. Is the Thermal Diagnostic event log no longer supported in Windows? It sounds useful to check if an overheated CPU was throttled due to overheating which could explain strange performance issues.

How would one detect CPU thermal throttling without that ETW provider?

[image]

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="" Guid="{68fdd900-4a3e-11d1-84f4-0000f80464e3}" /> 
  <EventID>0</EventID> 
  <Version>2</Version> 
  <Level>0</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>80</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-17T14:35:47.1453059Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>0</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1876" ThreadID="11924" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power/Thermal-Diagnostic</Channel> 
  <Computer>IMW1015103C.ad005.onehc.net</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <ProcessingErrorData>
  <ErrorCode>15003</ErrorCode> 
  <DataItemName /> 
  <EventPayload>000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```